# CosmosDb SELECT multiple values with LINQ query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

What will be the LINQ equivalent of this cosmos SQL API query:

```
SELECT c as Person, ST_DISTANCE(c.location, {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates':[-122.3382419, 47.6074856]}) as Distance
FROM c 
WHERE  c.DocType = 0 AND 
ST_DISTANCE(c.location, {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates':[-123.3382419, 47.6074856]}) < 1 AND NOT c.Blocked
```

which gets back

```
[
    {
        "Person": {
            "DocType": 0,
            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -123.3382419,
                    47.6074856
                ]
            },
            "MDS": "Chwal",
            "Description": "Bduwhs",
            "Contents": null,
            "GFree": false,
            "Veg": false,
            "AllergicContents": null,
            "Calorie": 0,
            "LinkToRecipe": null,
            "Cost": 36,
            "DASD": "Mexican",
            "ExpirationTime": "2019-12-17T11:30:52Z",
            "Images": [
                "test/25254932-2898-5fd7-949b-b2feb25a4964"
            ],
            "ProducerUserId": "1b36c0f1-425c-483a-bb01-69b06e69f203",
            "ExchangeDateTimeStartInUtc": "2019-12-17T20:30:52Z",
            "ExchangeDateTimeEndInUtc": "2019-12-17T19:30:52Z",
            "Blocked": false,
            "id": "asd,
            "_rid": "asd=="

        },
        "Distance": 0.1
    }
]
```

The problem with ST_DISTANCE is that it can only be calculated on Cosmos db, and can't be post evaluated.

Comment: I'm afraid that `ST_DISTANCE` is not supported in cosmos db linq according to this MS doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do it other than writing SQL query string

```
DocumentDBRepository.RunQueryAsync(
from c in DocumentDBRepository.DocumentQuery<Person>()
where c.DocType == 0
&& c.Location.Distance(point) < 1
&& !c.Blocked
select new { Person = c, Distance = c.Location.Distance(point) });
```

Also realized that LINQ lambda is different from a LINQ query. The above is a LINQ query, A LINQ lambda looks like [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/blob/c6f84ae063ad6bac636b2949d7a0dab3f0c59c8b/samples/code-samples/Queries/Program.cs#L199)